# A question about some sequence in a Banach space

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be an infinite dimensional Banach space and let $\left( x_{n}\right)
_{n\in 
%TCIMACRO{\U{2115} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{N}
%EndExpansion
}$ be a sequence of vectors such that :

$d\left( x_{n,}span\left\{ x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{n-1}\right\} \right)
=\left\Vert x_{n}\right\Vert $, for every $n\in 
%TCIMACRO{\U{2115} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{N}
%EndExpansion
$.

My question is : can we conclude that for every vector $x$ in $span\left\{
x_{n},x_{n+1},...\right\} $ we have $d\left( x_{,}span\left\{
x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{n-1}\right\} \right) =\left\Vert x\right\Vert$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

For example, in $\ell^\infty$, take $x_n$ with $(x_n)_n \ge |(x_n)_j|$ for $j < n$ and $(x_n)_j = 0$ for $j > n$.  This satisfies the requirements.  But you could have e.g. $x_1 = (1, 0\ldots)$, $x_2 = (1,1,0\ldots)$, $x_3 = (1,0,1,0\ldots)$, and $x_2 + x_3 = (2,1,1,0,\ldots)$ with $d(x_2+x_3, 
\text{span}(x_1) = 1$ while $\|x_2 + x_3\| = 2$.